# jquery load - ok, but something missing that I only get when refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, load

On my website, I have two radio buttons that toggle different radio station.

When I click on a radio button (the same or other station), it does that :

```
onclick="changestream('stationname')"

function changestream(radio) {
    $('#player').load('player.php?radio='+radio);
    $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php');
}
```

The problem is that everytime I click the button, a new listener adds up (in my icecast status page). But there should be only 1 listener.

If I refresh the complete page on clicking the button, no new listener is added. That's what I want.

So, with 'load', something is missing.
Something related with browser cache ?

What could I do to clear everything as in a refresh, but without actually refreshing the page ?

Thanks for help,

Patrick

Comment: Do you need to be running the changestream() function when the page loads for the radio that is clicked by default?

Comment: No, the changestream() function is not running when refreshing the page. But on refresh, the two load() occur.

Comment: I realised this is happenning when I use jPlayer, but not my other flash player.